# Where is the ring-signature article by luigi1111 referenced in the multi-part stealth-address steemit post?

Tags: stealth-address

Luigi1111's [post](https://steemit.com/monero/@luigi1111/understanding-monero-cryptography-privacy-part-2-stealth-addresses) about stealth-addresses, references throughout that how the stealth addresses are spent from would be covered in a follow-up RingCT article. However, I can't find this follow-up article. Did he ever write it?

Also is Luigi1111 Ricardo Spagni or another dev? I'm specifically looking for his follow up, not a link to any paper on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

> Did he never write it?

To my knowledge, that follow-up article has not been written.

However, an excellent resource for everything Monero is the [Zero to Monero](https://www.getmonero.org/library/Zero-to-Monero-1-0-0.pdf) paper (which includes ring-sigantures).

> Also is Luigi1111 Ricardo Spagni or another dev?

They are not the same person.

Comment: yes, I believe that one must be the next best thing.

Comment: and what is your suggestion for understanding bulletproofs aside from the stanford link?

Comment: I actually found the Quarkslab bulletproof [audit](https://blog.quarkslab.com/resources/2018-10-22-audit-monero-bulletproof/18-06-439-REP-monero-bulletproof-sec-assessment.pdf) pretty helpful in understanding bulletproofs.

Comment: how about zksnarks. Do you have a favorite suggestion there?

Comment: Nope. Not Monero.